# Cannot install pecl/pear packages

Tags: php

I'm using rasapbian jessie I'm attempting to install pecl_http, raphf, propro and other php modules but I'm getting the following error when I run `sudo pecl install pecl_http` etc:

`pecl/pecl_http requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.30-0+deb8u1
pecl/raphf requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.30-0+deb8u1
pecl/propro requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.30-0+deb8u1
No valid packages found
install failed`

However, I can't install php7 from raspbian repositories.

Comment: Can I ask you how you installed pecl? I have the opposite problem. I installed `php7.0-dev` and when I run `pecl install [anything]` I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Frontend.php on line 91` because the code is not PHP7 compatible!

Comment: Ha! Now I uninstalled php7 and went back to php5, and then I get the same error message as you... Good gracious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php7.0 is not available in the official repository, you can use some other trusted private repositories. This is what you should do in order to install phpp7.0 form [mati75's](http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/) private repository(Also read this [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo) ) :

**1.First, remove the php version that you already have installed :**

`sudo apt-get purge php*`

This will remove the current installation of php and php extensions from your Pi.

**2.Now add the repository sources to your sources.list :**

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then add these line to the end of that file :

```
deb http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Save the file and exit nano by Ctrl + O then Enter and Ctrl + X

**3.Add the repository public keys by running :**

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key CCD91D6111A06851
```

and,

```
 sudo gpg --armor --export CCD91D6111A06851 | apt-key add -
```

**4.Update the package list :**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**5.Install php7.0 :**

`sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-dev`

You can also install php extensions like this.

**6.Check the version :**

```
php -v
```

Comment: It's been suggested by another user that `php7.0-dev` be added to the list.  I don't know if that's necessary for building some pecl/pear modules.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've approved that edit.